# Very Simple URL Rewrite withou Regex

Tags: url-rewriting

for a site move I need to hardcode some very simple URL Rewrites. I only see examples with regular expressions but what I need is this:

I have a CSV like

```
new URL, old URL
http://shop.example.com/categoryB, http://example.com/shop/categoryC
```

as you see, as the category names are not the same, there is no Regex magic necessary, I just want to create a .htaccess file with one URL Rewrite per line, that's it.

I tried

```
RewriteRule http://shop.example.com/categoryB http://example.com/shop/categoryC [L,R=301]
```

but this doesn't seem to work,

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer looks like this:

RedirectMatch 301 /categoryOLDSITE http://example.com/shop/categoryNEWSITE

important is the slash in front of the old site and that it isn't a complete URL but a relative one to the location of the .htaccess file.

further information here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on the ReWrite engine at the start of your htaccess file?

I would guess at something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 http://shop.example.com/categoryB http://example.com/shop/categoryC
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. to clarify:

I put this in .htaccess on the old server. the URL of the new site is ..categoryC, the URL on the old server for which the redirect should occur is ..categoryB - right?